# If aliens would be like us, how can we survive

Tags: science-fiction, aliens, survival, far-future, augmented-reality

We Humans are the most intelligent species of this planet, we have total control over all other species of this planet, we can use them however we want like (Food,clothes,experiments). We are the most harmful species for our planets and other living beings, because we only focus on self-benefits.

Now question is if aliens can also exploit their power like us, then how can we survive? (Assume that aliens have many time more advance technology than us) The noticeable thing is technology advancement doesn't necessarily make us wise (prime example humans).

Aliens would be many times more powerful than us so fighting against them would be useless. Maybe the only option left is argument, so what kind of argument can we put on table.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90334/discussion-on-question-by-earthling-if-aliens-would-be-like-us-how-can-we-surv).

Answer (score 5):

How do smart animals survive on Earth?

1. Be unthreatening - Great apes in jungles are largely left alone if they keep away from human settlements.
2. Be a companion - Cats, dogs and myriad other species live as pets in close proximity with humans, albeit they must never show behaviour which would harm a human, or are kept in conditions which prevent it (cages, tanks)
3. Be insignificant - unless rodents or insects cause problems to people, we ignore them
4. Be contained - Many predators live in enclosed spaces - wildlife parks, protected areas, reservations.
5. Be useful - animals were, at one time, the main source of motor power (literally, the workhorses)

Those, broadly, are our options. The problem, though, is that as an intelligent species which has already demonstrated its supreme desire for freedom, any of those options besides a mix of #1 and #4 is likely to be unpalatable. Survival is survival, so presumably some people might take those options, but groups of people are unlikely to do so without repeated episodes of dissent and unrest. To suggest we would collectively accept such things would be a mockery of the history of civil rights.

This, to my mind, leaves some form of contained exclusion; we agree not to breach some boundary if they will leave us alone. Unfortunately such a state would be only temporary.

Comment: Your only valid point is 3 in my opinion, because human population is too big, Maybe they don't need all humans for their experiment (That depends on what kind of experiment ) , you can also try this for understand how worse we are ,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BrlBSuuy50Y&t=7s

Answer (score 4):

Diplomacy.

These aliens would be looking at the same stuff we do: companionship, satisfying our needs for food, shelter and sex and doing this all through technology and resources. Many of us also have ideologies like protecting wildlife or equal rights.

When the aliens meet us they could wipe us out, but why would they? They would be better off supplying us with technology and making us a viable trading partner. This way it becomes easier to satisfy their own needs, and our view on technology could ultimately help them discover better technology themselves.

If more nefarious individuals of the species meet us they could simply see an opportunity for cheap labor for tasks their own species dont want to do anymore, similar to how first-world countries will have many individuals from poor countries employed in such tasks. A more extreme case might see humanity in (wage) slave labor... Possibly without us knowing it. Why waste precious money and resources on expensive asteroid miners who will want massive payment for being away from their families for months, if you can convince a few starry-eyed humans that they could get filthy rich for each shipment they get but you pay them with what are trinkets and tourist crap to you but advanced ultra-tech to us humans?

Comment: If the aliens are like us to answer the question why would they wipe us out just open a history book. Spanish colonization of the America's, Manifest Destiny, Turkish genocide of the Armenians, the Holocaust, repopulation of Prussia after the Northern Crusades, resettling regime of the Neo Assyrians and Soviet Russians. Current Chinese policies in Tibet.

Comment: @Demigan you should refer Phil H 's ans. It's more realistic. Maybe they don't need to kills us but that doesn't mean that they would treat us like guest, In my scenario alien are like us(Selfish) , like we are exploiting our power of Intelligent on other specie for self benefits they will also use their's. if u don't know how are we exploiting our power then you should watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BrlBSuuy50Y&t=7s

Comment: @Mormacil the question is how we survive. History is indeed filled with tragedy but for the same reason that the local news is filled with tragedy: good news simply isnt that interesting. Most of those historical stories tell you that cooperation is key. WWII started because we didnt cooperate with Germany when WWI ended, after WWII they learned their lesson and did not sink Germany with massive debts and punishments. Now its a prosperous country and a hard defender against prosecution and random murder. But you dont find many pages devoted to that last part like the fall to WWII gets.

Comment: @Earthling so they arent like us, they are caricatures of our greed and invasiveness. That is completely different from what you ask.

Comment: Modern scholars consider WW1 and WW2 to be a single conflict. And east Germany exited WW2 and later the Soviet Union with massive debt. The Soviets also punished the Germans horribly at the end of WW2. And it's not just in the past. ISIS did ethnic cleansing, Myanmar targeted the Royingha about a year ago? Why would similar aliens not act as humans when they got a severe power advantage?

Comment: @Demigan why you are comparing war between humans and war between different species, because war between different species can be many time more worse than human( u can observe ourselves , how we are treating animals)

Comment: @earthling We're in no way at war with any animals except Emus and as far as wars go that one was quite bloodless. So if anything evidence says interspecies wars are less bloody then human wars.

Comment: @ Mormacil you are right but also supporting my argument, Animal can't put fight against us because we are that much superior. we have total control over their life,we can use them for food as much as we want, we can kill for entertainment(hunting), we can do all kind of experiment on them, they are hopeless, they have to die even if they don't want , they can't negotiate like us human. my points are quite clear, For aliens we are also like animal . what u think what  is much better, war between humans or aliens

Comment: @earthling because you say that these aliens are like us, so their reasons for waging war would be the same. About the video: if I showed you a video of all the benevolence and support humans give on a daily basis, would you think humanity is all rainbows and sunshine? Ofcourse not, humans are a complex bunch with a lit of nuance on why we do everything.

Comment: @Demiagan Human are complex , they have different morels and onions but that doesn't change the overall outcome as species , Other species and environment is paying price for our selfish actions. we are cancer for this planet. you are right about their nothing can be done about our this behaviour, I am not stating this comment as argument for my question because i can't feel offence from your replay

Comment: @earthling if you make someone care for the meat they are going to eat or do the animal tests themselves before they are allowed to use the makeup or medicine and the quality of life for these animals will rise, and the amount of harmful/deadly tests will plummet. This is because humans will allow bad things to happen if there is distance between them, as well as cause. Few people will enjoy hunting animals and they'll enjoy hunting more if they shoot something they cant relate to, IE a small bird rather than a dog.

Comment: We cant give our cattle equipment and expect them to use it, but the more they can while we can identify ourselves in them the less likely we'll be killing them. IE our pets. These aliens would be able to school us and give us equipment, and if they teach one generation we could already be equal to the aliens. This isnt a fly that anyone will randomly kill because it irritates them, this is a sentient being they could relate to, communicate with, enjoy their company, work alongside and benefit from eachothers insights.

Answer (score 0):

1. because they are far away and restriction to lightspeed means that invasions wouldn't make any sense (and more important the needed energy for transport is far to big to make it worthwile - it's so incredibly easier to just mine some asteroids or similar)
2. because they can kill us, doesn't mean they will want to (we don't kill all animals either)

In fact - killing stuff from space is so easy, it doesn't need much technology - just drop some rocks and you're done. You pretty much can't defend against that at all and aliens wouldn't need to be that far above us.

Same goes for anybody else who left our gravity well - even fellow humans. The only two ways to not getting killed are:

1. don't fight
2. diversify where you are - thousands inhabited asteroids are far harder to destroy than a single planet

Comment: @ Dr.Azrael Self Interest can be driving force for them to use us against our will.
Self Interest like Experiment, Controlling us , maybe impregnating our women (playing role of god) etc

Comment: The chance their they can impregnate our women as aliens from another star system are near impossible, our biologies would simply be to different. We can't even procreate with chimps and they're like 98% similar in DNA.

Comment: @Mormacil they can make artificial sperm by using our own DNA, my concern is forcefully

Comment: You mean they can manufacture human sperm to impregnate human women? Why would they do that? If they want to breed more humans forced copulation is far easier and cheaper. If it's about experimentation, using animals is far easier and a solid alternative. There is no logical reason to use humans for that.

Comment: Defending against asteroids is easier than it looks, assuming its not a relativistic object and it can be detected in time. If you can get a sattelite nearby a month before impact, you can use a laser and ablation or a small bomb to send it off-course. A tiny nudge is enough in astronomical terms to get one to miss earth. The Armageddon movie could have planted just one nuke on the side and it would probably have done the job